# AttributeError: module 'jinja2.ext' has no attribute 'autoescape' while trying to use Flask-Babel

Tags: python, flask, python-babel

I am new to Flask and Babel and I have just started a project which will contain several languages. After I have generated the babel.cfg file, when I attempt to extract it with the command `pybabel extract -F babel.cfg -o messages.pot .`, I get the `AttributeError: module 'jinja2.ext' has no attribute 'autoescape'`  error.

What can be the reason for this error and how can I fix it?

Thank you

Answer (score 18, accepted):

With `Jinja2 3.1`, `WithExtension` and `AutoEscapeExtension` are built-in now. So you don't need these extensions anymore.
Delete these extension from babel.cfg file

```
[python: **.py]
[jinja2: **/templates/**.html]
;extensions=jinja2.ext.auto escape,jinja2.ext.with_
```

https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/changes/#version-3-0-0

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you are using Python 3.10 and Jinja2 version >= 3.x.x

The extension `jinja2.ext.autoescape` and `jinja2.ext.with`have been deprecated with Jinja2 version 3.0.0! They have been added to the compiler.

Link to changes: https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/changes/#version-3-0-0